# React Native Base Toast error

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have the following React Native App set up and I'm trying to use the Toast component from Native Base:

**app.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import { Root } from "native-base";
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import MainView from './assets/screens/MainView';
import ConfigView from './assets/screens/ConfigView';

export default class myApp extends Component {

render() {
  return (
    <Root>
    <AppNavigator />
  </Root>
  );
}
}
const Screens = StackNavigator({
  Main: {screen: MainView},
  Config: {screen: ConfigView}
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => Screens);
```

**MainView.js (simplified)**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleProvider, Card, CardItem, Left, Right, Body, Icon, Toast, Header, Fab } from 'native-base';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class MainView extends Component {
....
  showError = (msg, err) => {
    console.log("[ERROR]", err);
    Toast.show({
      text: msg,
      position: this.state.toastPosition,
      buttonText: this.state.toastErrorBtn
    });
  }
....
}
```

I've tried several ways, but keep getting this error:

[image: error capture]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app should start with rendering `myApp` component, like this:
`AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => myApp);`.

Inside `myApp` you should render your app navigator which is `Screens` not `AppNavigator`, that is how you named it.

This is how your app.js should look:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Root } from "native-base";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import MainView from './assets/screens/MainView';
import ConfigView from './assets/screens/ConfigView';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

export default class myApp extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <Root>
            <Screens />
        </Root>
      );
    }
}
const Screens = StackNavigator({
    Main: {screen: MainView},
    Config: {screen: ConfigView}
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => myApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
We should use Root component

import { Root } from "native-base";

<Root>
  // Screen
</Root>
```